# Google Realtime circular JSON error when indexReference stored in collaborative map only when contained in an object

Tags: json, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Trying to store indexReferences per user, I've found that when I store one (or more) directly in a map, it works fine. However, when stored in an object (or a custom realtime object), the realtime API generates Circular JSON errors.

This works fine:

```
function doRegisterTypes() {
    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.registerType(MyCustomType, "MyCustomType");
    MyCustomType.prototype.startPoints = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('startPoints');
    MyCustomType.prototype.endPoints = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('endPoints');
    MyCustomType.prototype.elements = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('elements');

    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.setInitializer(MyCustomType, initializeMyCustomType);
}

function initializeMyCustomType() {
    var model = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel(this);
    this.startPoints = model.createMap();
    this.endPoints = model.createMap();
    this.elements = model.createList();
}

function initializeModel(model) {
    var o = model.create("MyCustomType");
    o.elements.pushAll(["foo", "bar"]);
    var startIndex = o.elements.registerReference(0, false);
    var endIndex = o.elements.registerReference(0, false);
    o.startPoints.set(UserId, startIndex);
    o.endPoints.set(UserId, endIndex);

    model.getRoot().set("MyCustomObject", o);
}
```

But this doesn't, failing with circular JSON errors when storing the range object in the map:

```
function doRegisterTypes() {
    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.registerType(MyCustomType, "MyCustomType");
    MyCustomType.prototype.ranges = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('ranges');
    MyCustomType.prototype.elements = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.collaborativeField('elements');

    gapi.drive.realtime.custom.setInitializer(MyCustomType, initializeMyCustomType);
}

function initializeMyCustomType() {
    var model = gapi.drive.realtime.custom.getModel(this);
    this.ranges = model.createMap();
    this.elements = model.createList();
}

function initializeModel(model) {
    var o = model.create("MyCustomType");
    o.elements.pushAll(["foo", "bar"]);
    var startIndex = o.elements.registerReference(0, false);
    var endIndex = o.elements.registerReference(0, false);

    // FAILS:
    o.ranges.set(UserId, {start:startIndex, end:endIndex});

    model.getRoot().set("MyCustomObject", o);
}
```

I should stress the error appears for a single indexReference, and whether the object is a specific custom type or not, and also WHENEVER the value is set into the map: while initializing the model or later. It's as if the indexReferences cannot be stored at anything but a "top level", though that makes little sense.

Feature? Bug? User stoopidity?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?  what is o.ranges?

Comment: @Cheryl Simon I'll get you the error message, but o.ranges is the map as set in the second example's initializeMyCustomType routine.

Comment: @CherylSimon Here's the error:  Error in listener function: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at Object.stringify (native)  
...plus a bunch more.

Answer (score 1):

You can't store CollaborativeObjects within arbitrary json within a CollaborativeObject.  CollaborativeObjects (including IndexReferences) must be stored directly in other CollaborativeObjects.

(There are a few reasons for this, mostly having to do with how the collaboration works.. json objects are treated as arbitrary blobs whose contents are ignored.)

In this case, you could create a Range custom object type that has a start and end CollaborativeField.  (Or a CollaborativeList with 2 elements..)

Comment: As I said in the original question, it happens even when I create a custom object, in this case a Range object with a start and end...

Comment: Oh, sorry I missed that... that's probably a bug.  Do you have a link to a repro page?  We'll look into it.  Meanwhile, a 2 element CollabList should work :-/

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it... you were right, but there's a bit more to it: In the initialize routine for the Range custom type, I was setting start and end to null (didn't work) or to {} (didn't work). My foolishness perhaps, but there's no need to set them to anything at that point, or indeed initialize the type at all.

Comment: Ah, ok, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Don't know if it could be regarded as a bug, but once they're set at all, setting them to an indexReference draws the foul.

Comment: Yeah, that should probably not blow up.  I'll file a bug.